# K-means clustering algorithm

Tags: python, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to get this image:

[image]

But I got this image:

[image]

how can i change the color?

Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

def kmeans_clustering(image, K):
    pixels = image.reshape((-1, 3)).astype(np.float32)
    pixels_normalized = pixels / 255.0
    np.random.seed(0)
    centers = np.random.rand(K, 3)
    iterations = 10
    for _ in range(iterations):
        
        distances = np.linalg.norm(pixels_normalized[:, np.newaxis] - centers, axis=2)
        labels = np.argmin(distances, axis=1)
        for i in range(K):
            cluster_pixels = pixels_normalized[labels == i]
            if len(cluster_pixels) > 0:
                centers[i] = np.mean(cluster_pixels, axis=0)
            
    centers_rgb = np.fliplr((centers * 255).astype(np.uint8))    
    segmented_image = centers_rgb[labels].reshape(image.shape)

    return segmented_image

image_rgb = cv.imread('sunflower.png')
image_rgb = cv.cvtColor(image_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

k_values = [2, 4, 6, 8]
segmented_images = []

for k in k_values:
    segmented_image = kmeans_clustering(image_rgb, k)
    segmented_images.append(segmented_image)

stacked_image = np.vstack((np.hstack((segmented_images[0], segmented_images[1])),
                           np.hstack((segmented_images[2], segmented_images[3]))))

cv.imshow('Segmented Image', stacked_image)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would like to have an image consisting of the following colors. Red, blue, green, and cyan, yellow:

[image]

Comment: What was the input?

Comment: red, blue, green, cyan, yellow.... and **white**?

Comment: input is any image. red, blue, green, cyan, yellow, and white.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way, simply by recoloring the layers in the kmeans processing in Python/OpenCV

- Read the input
- Convert to 1D array
- Do kmeans processing to get centers and labels
- Reconstitute 2D image from centers and labels
- Save the kmeans result with input colors
- Define k new colors
- Initialize a the new output as black
- Loop over each color (center)
- Copy the kmeans result as the layer
- Make a mask from the layer using cv2.inRange(layer, color, color)
- Apply the mask to make the layer black where the mask is black and to make the layer the new color where the mask is white
- Save the layer for the given color
- Composite the layer with the previous composited layers with a simple add (since black added to any color does not change the color)
- Save the final recolored kmeans image

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input and convert to range 0-1
image = cv2.imread('jellyfish.png')
h, w, c = image.shape

# reshape to 1D array
image_2d = image.reshape(h*w, c).astype(np.float32)

# set number of colors
numcolors = 6
numiters = 10
epsilon = 1
attempts = 10

# do kmeans processing
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, numiters, epsilon)
ret, labels, centers = cv2.kmeans(image_2d, numcolors, None, criteria, attempts, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

# reconstitute 2D image of results
centers = np.uint8(centers)
newimage = centers[labels.flatten()]
newimage = newimage.reshape(image.shape)

# save kmeans result with input colors
cv2.imwrite("jellyfish_kmeans.png", newimage)
cv2.imshow('new image', newimage)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# define new colors
red = [0,0,255]
green = [0,255,0]
blue = [255,0,0]
yellow = [0,255,255]
cyan = [255,255,0]
white = [255,255,255]
new_colors = [red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, white]

# initialize newimage_colors as black
newimage_colors = np.zeros((h,w,c), dtype=np.float32)

# loop over centers (input colors) and map to new colors
k = 0
for center in centers:

    # select center (original color) and create layer and mask
    layer = newimage.copy()
    mask = cv2.inRange(layer, center, center)

    # recolor layer color with new color and the rest black
    layer[mask==255] = new_colors[k]
    layer[mask==0] = [0,0,0]

    # save kmeans clustered layer for new color and show it
    cv2.imwrite("jellyfish_new_color{0}.png".format(k), layer)
    cv2.imshow('newimage_color_layer', layer)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # composite layers    
    newimage_colors = cv2.add(newimage_colors, layer)
    k = k + 1

cv2.imwrite("jellyfish_newcolors.png", newimage_colors)
cv2.imshow('newimage_colors', newimage_colors)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Kmeans result with original colors:

[image]

New layers for each of k new colors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Final Composited kmeans result with new colors[image]: